# What is the alternate of lookbehind regex in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, safari

What is the alternate of lookbehind regex in safari browser ?

I am using one regix where I want exclude http

Here is my regex :

```
value: /^((\w+)(?<!http):\/\/).+$/,
```

This is working fine in chrome but failing safari.  Any look around for this.

Comment: `/^(?!http:)\w+:\/\/.+$/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-vamp the lookbehind into a lookahead:

```
/^(?!http:)\w+:\/\/.+$/
```

Or even `/^(?!https?:)\w+:\/\/.+$/` to account for `https`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!http:)` - no `http:` allowed at the start
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `:\/\/` - `://` text
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string (redundant here though).

Answer (score 1):

select http:// or https://

```
/^(http|https):\/\//i
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ZAuzXy/1)